# What is Joomla /libraries/cms?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I had an issues with some joomla api. The issue was that I was using the latest version of joomla and couldn't find where a joomla class, that was being called in my code, was derived . I searched the joomla api docs and found nothing relating to the class I was looking for.

I then stumbled across the refactoring change log for joomla and noticed that the function i was after had actually been moved from `/libraries/joomla/form` to `libraries/cms/form`.

Why would this be the case? There doesn't seem to be any reference to `/libraries/cms` in the api docs. How are we suppose to know that there are classes living there? Very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Joomla! 1.6 the code has been progressively split into the Joomla! CMS and the Joomla! Platform. You can see this separation in the [github repository](https://github.com/joomla) - a good place to also keep track of changes that are committed to both the CMS and the Platform. The simplest way is [fork each repository and keep track of them](http://docs.joomla.org/Working_with_git_and_github).

As classes are updated they may be migrated to the `/libraries/cms` directory if they apply specifically to the CMS application (e.g. html forms are an application level function not a platform level).

I find the best place to hear about changes under discussion are in the respective Google Groups - [Joomla! Platform Development](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/joomla-dev-platform) and [Joomla! CMS Development](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/joomla-dev-cms)

**[Edit]**

Documentation of class's is the hardest thing to find for Joomla! CMS - there doesn't appear to be a *current* api listing for it, unlike [the Platform API reference](http://api.joomla.org/). Often it is just easier to read through the code.

It's also worth keeping a watch on the [developer sub-site](http://developer.joomla.org/).

Comment: Thanks cppl. I know there are only a few classes in CMS, but do they have documentation like the joomla! platform?

Comment: I haven't been able to find an up-to-date doc site for the CMS - see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to define excellence in CMS without coding, Joomla is the right option for you.Joomla the most preferred content management system among developers is an easy-to-use open source solution.If you want to define excellence in CMS without coding, Joomla is the right option for you. In this post, you will find few of its features that make the website development easy and most preferred option for developers.